How to type hint pandera checks without mypy errors
I am experiencing unexpected mypy errors when using pandera with the mypy plugin.
On windows, I am installing pandas, mypy, and pandera (with the mypy plugin) with the following command:
pip install pandas mypy pandera[mypy]
I then create a mypy.ini file with the following body:
[mypy]
plugins = pandera.mypy

I then create a test.py file with the following script taken from the pandera documentation:
import pandera as pa
from pandera.typing import Index, Series

class CustomCheckSchema(pa.DataFrameModel):

    a: Series[int] = pa.Field(gt=0, coerce=True)
    abc: Series[int]
    idx: Index[str]

    @pa.check("a", name="foobar")
    def custom_check(cls, a: Series[int]) -> Series[bool]:
        return a < 100

    @pa.check("^a", regex=True, name="foobar")
    def custom_check_regex(cls, a: Series[int]) -> Series[bool]:
        return a > 0

    @pa.check("idx")
    def check_idx(cls, idx: Index[int]) -> Series[bool]:
        return idx.str.contains("dog")

I expect no errors, as this is directly from the pandera documentation.  However, when running the command mypy test.py, the following errors occur:
test.py:12: error: Incompatible return value type (got "pandas.core.series.Series[bool]", expected "pandera.typing.pandas.Series[bool]")  [return-value]
test.py:16: error: Incompatible return value type (got "pandas.core.series.Series[bool]", expected "pandera.typing.pandas.Series[bool]")  [return-value]
test.py:20: error: Incompatible return value type (got "pandas.core.series.Series[bool]", expected "pandera.typing.pandas.Series[bool]")  [return-value]
Found 3 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)

Why does this occur, and how should I type hint my models so as to avoid these errors?
